# Group (for keeping changes local) in math

Tags: math-mode

With `\text\ensuremath`, I can keep changes (for spacing) local to a math group. But I hope that there is a nicer way. It should work with and without `unicode-math`.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  $x A - (x-1)B - (x-1)C$

  \newcommand\mgroup[1]{\text{\ensuremath{#1}}}  % <-- is there a nicer way to do this?
  \newcommand\tight[1]{\mgroup{\thinmuskip=0mu\medmuskip=0mu\thickmuskip=0mu #1}}
  $x A - (\tight{x-1})B - (\tight{x-1})C$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: TeX uses the values of `\thinmuskip`, `\medmuskip` and `\thickmuskip` that are in force when a formula ends, when starting to translate the math list into boxes and glue. So there's no way to set such parameters to different values in the same formula. Your trick uses different formulas, which is why it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TeX uses the values of `\thinmuskip`, `\medmuskip` and `\thickmuskip` that are in force when a formula ends, when starting to translate the math list into boxes and glue. So there's no way to set such parameters to different values in the same formula. Your trick uses different formulas, which is why it works.

Here's a plain TeX example showing `\thinmuskip` that's automatically inserted between `\log` and `x`:

```
$\thinmuskip=10mu \log x+
{\thinmuskip=20mu \log x}+
\log x\thinmuskip=3mu$

\bye
```

As you can see, the value used is the standard one, that has been reestablished at the end:

[image]

If I remove the last setting, we get

[image]

where the value used is 10mu, because the setting to 20mu is forgotten at the end of the group.

Note that your trick can more simply be `\text{<settings>$<formula>$}` because inside `\text` TeX is in (restricted) horizontal mode.

Comment: So, you say "math in `\text` in math" is a proper solution, despite it looks a little bit weird?

Comment: @mhchem Sure! I see no other method.